# Create new page when changing ID

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, tcpdf

Good afternoon, I'm generating a report in PDFand I need to generate a new page when I change the user code.

---

**It is thus generating**

### [image: Report].

At the moment he is only inserting the line of the items and ignoring the order, he has to mount the same ones of the top that are correct, creating in a new page a new heading `(Aspecto físico, habilidade motora e Inteligencia de jogo)` and inserting the items in its proper place.

---

**PHP**

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($area_avaliar); $i++) {
        $cur_atleta = $area_avaliar[$i]->cod_atleta_area_avaliar;
        if($cur_atleta != $pre_atleta){
            if ($area_avaliar_tecnica[$i]->descricao_tecnica != $area_avaliar_tecnica[$i-1]->descricao_tecnica) {
                $this->pdf->Multicell(175, 5, $area_avaliar_tecnica[$i]->descricao_tecnica, 1, 'L', 1);
            }
                $this->pdf->Multicell(175, 5, $area_avaliar[$i]->desc_area_avaliar_item.' = '.$area_avaliar[$i]->avaliacao, 1, 'L', 1);
                $ultimo_cod = $area_avaliar[$i]->cod_atleta_area_avaliar;
                $this->pdf->addPage();
        }
        $pre_atleta = $area_avaliar[$i]->cod_atleta_area_avaliar;
    }
```

I'm trying to do with this code, I need every time `cod_atleta_area_avaliar` (id name) change, it creates a new page (`$this-> pdf->addPage()`) and put it back in the same structure, with the headers and items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach:

```
    $pre_atleta = ''; // init

    for ($k=0; $k < count($area_avaliar); $k++) {
        $cur_atleta = $area_avaliar[$k]->cod_atleta_area_avaliar;
        if($cur_atleta != $pre_atleta){
            // new page
            $this->pdf->addPage();
            // ...... other pdf instructions ...
        }
        $pre_atleta = $area_avaliar[$k]->cod_atleta_area_avaliar;
    }
```

Comment: I updated the question the way I tried to, but it still did not work.